# What's the best way to modify a bitwise Karatsuba-Algorithm to work with negative numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, multiplication, karatsuba

I wrote this bitwise Karatsuba multiplication algorithm. It does not use strings or `math.pow`. It's just divide-and-conquer-recursion, bitwise operations and addition:

```
def karatsuba(x,y):
  n = max(x.bit_length(), y.bit_length())

  if n < 2:
    return x&y

  # split in O(1)
  n = (n + 1) >> 1

  b = x >> n;
  a = x - (b << n);
  d = y >> n;
  c = y - (d << n);

  ac = karatsuba(a, c);
  bd = karatsuba(b, d);
  abcd = karatsuba(a+b, c+d);

  return ac + ((abcd - ac - bd) << n) + (bd << (n << 1));

print(karatsuba(23,24))
print(karatsuba(-29,31))

# 552
# 381
```

It works absolutly fine with positive numbers, but obviously -29*31 is not equal 381.

What's the easiest way to fix the problem?

My first idea was to make the number positive with `(~(-29)+1) = 29`, store wheather it was negative or not in a boolean and handle that boolean in my return statement, but is there a better (maybe bitwise) solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wrote: "My first idea was to make the number positive with (~(-29)+1) = 29, store wheather it was negative or not in a boolean and handle that boolean in my return statement, but is there a better (maybe bitwise) solution?"

Comment: And... best is subjective, easiest is (probably) subjective.

Comment: Regardless, (some code review) (1) You don't need `(~x+1)`, just `-x`.  (2) The split part takes `O(n)` (where `n` is the bit length of the input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your exit case, in particular `x&y` returns the wrong value for negative numbers:

```
-1 & 1 == 1   # Needs to return -1
```

So you can fix this with testing for it or or just returning:

```
if n < 2:
    return x*y
```

E.g.:

```
In []:
print(karatsuba(-29,31))

Out[]:
-899
```

Comment: Sry, the idea of this was to calculate the product without the " * ". But the answer in your comment (under the question) helped me. I created a dictionary: table = {
  (-1,-1): 1, (-1,0): 0, (-1, 1): -1,
  (0,-1): 0, (0,0):0, (0,1): 0,
  (1,-1): -1, (1,0): 0, (1,1): 1} and called   if n < 2: return table[(x,y)]. Add it and I'll accept your answer. Still in O(1) if I'm right.

Comment: Yes, a lookup table would be `O(1)` and would avoid `*`.